# How to copy a hard drive that is not formated

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I have a hard drive from a PS3 that I am trying to copy to a portable hard drive. I am trying to do this without deleting data from the portable hard drive. Does any one know of a program or a way to do this?

Comment: So in other words how do you copy a RAW hard drive.

Comment: Usually the answer to this is `dd`. Just do `dd if=/dev/sdX of=<image file> bs=16M` where sdX is the source drive and <image file> is the destination filename. I don't know if a PS3 drive requires any special handling, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clonezilla, a live OS purpose-built for copying filesystems or raw devices (partition or full disk). You'll have to attach both disks at the same time (but you knew that), and you
might want to **detach** any other drives from your system to avoid accidents. Clonezilla is free, runs on many architectures, and doesn't take long to download, so it should be a good fit for your scenario. http://clonezilla.org/